# You'd better have a good reason to keep the [light] on while I'm programming

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[Spoken *strictly* from my experiences in comfortable, dark offices with minimal noise.]

Note that this isn't a duplicate; the duplicate being suggested has *no* plan of action, whereas here we're at least discussing synonymization.

I stumbled upon the [light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/light) tag today.  It has 318 questions at the moment. One top answerer has answered 5 questions; everyone else has answered just 1.  A couple of the top askers have asked 2 questions; everyone else has asked just 1.  I'm not really sure what purpose it serves.

Its short description is:

> light is basis for our visual perception

...which is not reassuring, but then we go into *this* awesome detail for the actual tag wiki!

> Light consist of particles called photons can behave like corpuscular
>   beam and wave
>
> basic physical properties are:
>
> - energy
> - wavelength (frequency) for monochromatic sources
> - energy spectrum for chromatic sources
> - speed of propagation (different in different materials)
> - polarization
>
> Other properties
>
> - color
>
>   - it is not an physical property it is Human perception of visible light bands instead
>   - different light spectrum sources can have the same color perception for a group of people
>   - human color perception is not the same between persons/gender/race
>   - local region average measurements are the base for color perception estimation systems
>   - color perception defects are
>   - either defect in eye perception cells
>   - or just different excitation bands/shape for X,Y,Z curves ...

I can't even be warm or fuzzy about this.  This just feels ***wrong***.

If I'm taking this wiki at face value, the [light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/light) tag is meant to be used for questions:

- relating to lighting of some kind,
- relating to dealing with lighting physics, or
- relating to the lack of lighting of some kind.

[Some of the questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773697/measuring-light-intensities-from-android-camera) [relating to this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906993/what-is-a-normal-in-opengl), as highly voted as they may be, don't really *relate* to light as a property itself; they relate to a piece of the puzzle in their problem.  The first question could even be considered too broad, because they're essentially trying to create some kind of medical device but have "no clue where to start".

So...

My immediate thought is to turn off the light.  Does anyone really want to keep it on?  Please, I work best in less-bright environments.

Comment: It would be a delight to burninate this tag.

Comment: If it's not burninated, the tag wiki definitely needs to be edited so that it's less ambiguous. There's also a [lighting tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lighting), which I feel does a better job of being on-topic. I don't currently see how this tag is useful.

Comment: You did better than me, I gave up formatting it and took a screen shot

Comment: [Light] it on fire.

Comment: Attack the [light]!

Comment: This is not be taken lightly. That is my POV.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn off the \[light\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298681/turn-off-the-light)

Comment: @NathanTuggy maybe the other way around, as this has answers?

Comment: Tag not meant for light hearted discussion.

Comment: @DanielJames do enlighten me? :)

Comment: Looks like the synonym idea proposed in the accepted answer was chosen as the best approach here. Can you take a small look and let me know if the same holds true even to this day? Thank you.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From comment feedback we can make [light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/light)  and [shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shadow) synonyms of [lighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lighting) (not [lightning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lightning) ;))

I've created a suggested edit for the [lighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lighting)

Excerpt:

> Related to computer games' engines and 3d graphics software. For the
>   use of both shadow and light in GUIs and for the use of lighting with
>   respect to programs using hardware such as cameras, that requires code
>   to control the lighting. Must be used with other relevant tags
>   distinguishing the programming language and framework being used. e.g.
>   unity 3d Not to be used with light, as is used in physics having wave
>   and particle characteristics.

And added a wiki:

> Questions related to drawing or setting shadows on an object. It
>   refers to graphical shadow in user interfaces and not to be confused
>   with conceptual shadows (copies) of an object, library, database etc.
>
> Questions related to drawing or setting light on an object, or
>   programming questions on controlling light values within a program
>   e.g. controlling light within a program that uses a camera.
>
> Not to be used with light, as is used in physics having wave and
>   particle characteristics.
>
> The use of the light tag here is as light is exposed within a
>   graphical user interface and how to alter the settings and angles of
>   the light. e.g. unity3d
>
> For use of programming in e.g. Android where a program may be written
>   that utilizes the camera and programming filters affecting the
>   selection of light through the camera.

I'm posting a second answer, so we can distinguish between whether people want the tag to stay or want it synonmised.

Comment: I'm not sure that [tag:shadow] should be a synonym of [tag:lighting].  While they're closely related in the real world, they are very different in computer algorithms.  It's expensive to simulate individual light rays, so algorithms which calculate lighting based on positions, colors, and normals are used instead.  These algorithms can't tell if there's anything between an object and the light source, so techniques like shadow mapping must be used.

Comment: @NobodyNada nobody (pun intended) is suggesting they're the same techniques, they come under the same umbrella of what is being achieved and there is overlap.

Comment: I disagree that there's enough overlap for them to use the same tag.  Lighting can be incredibly complex, and shadows can as well.  The results of the shadow algorithms may be used as input to a lighting algorithm, but other than that they rarely overlap at all.

Comment: @NobodyNada ok, if you think the tag you stay and has merits, have a look at my other answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345286/3956566 :) I don't mind which. I don't think the tag should be destroyed.

Comment: Synonymization is probably the better option here.  If they can both fit under lighting then I'd be okay with this.  Before we do that, though, I'd love to see if there are questions that need to be closed/removed beforehand.

Comment: @Makoto yes definitely. I had a quick browse and the one's I saw were ok. But there's sufficient in numbers for both tags to warrant a coordinated effort to check them and retag. As long as we don't use [tag:lightning] ;) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345284/youd-better-have-a-good-reason-to-keep-the-light-on-while-im-programming/345293?noredirect=1#comment455740_345286

Comment: Well, we could do a bit of a lightning round and clean that tag up too, while we're at it...

Comment: @Makoto I'll post that one in socvr for rene ;)

Comment: Sure you are not just making a lightening rod for your back? 8-P

Comment: Now we just need someone with enough points in the tag to suggest the synonym lol

Answer (score 4):

The tag has valid programming merits. Just as [shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shadow) has.

The issue was the tag wiki and excerpt, which is about light as a physics definition with particle and wavelike properties.

[image]

Many of the questions are appropriately tagged with programming language or framework tags and refer to light as a on topic programming question.

e.g.

[2D light diffuse map artefact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205170/2d-light-diffuse-map-artefact)

[Is there any way to filter out specific wavelengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39795394/is-there-any-way-to-filter-out-specific-wavelengths)

There's questions where the tag in a useful programming sense is not used appropriately and it will be simple enough to edit the tag out of those question.

I've created new excerpt:

> Questions related to drawing or setting light on an object, for use in
>   GUI, or programming questions on controlling light values within a
>   program e.g. controlling light within a program that uses a camera.
>   Not to be used with light, as is used in physics having wave and
>   particle characteristics. Must be used with other relevant tags
>   distinguishing the programming language and framework being used. e.g.
>   unity 3d

and wiki edit suggestions:

> Questions related to drawing or setting light on an object, or
>   programming questions on controlling light values within a program
>   e.g. controlling light within a program that uses a camera.
>
> Not to be used with light, as is used in physics having wave and
>   particle characteristics.
>
> The use of the light tag here is as light is exposed within a
>   graphical user interface and how to alter the settings and angles of
>   the light. e.g. unity3d
>
> For use of programming in e.g. Android where a program may be written
>   that utilizes the camera and programming filters affecting the
>   selection of light through the camera.

If [shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shadow) is valid, then so is [light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/light) as both effects are used in GUIs. It depends on how specific we want out tags.

Comment: Well, wouldn't *both* this tag and [tag:shadow] potentially be better suited under [tag:lighting]?  I'm not convinced that this tag should be here at all, and you haven't exactly sold me on it either.

Comment: @Makoto ironically, my first instinct was, *yeh, burn it*, but when I went and checked it out I thought hm, it has a use case here. Shadow effects are specific and different to light effects. Both are relevant in GUIs. Also the use case of light with respect to filtering out with a camera is different to shadow.

Comment: It's a bit late so I don't have the stamina to focus on the camera angle, but speaking from just the light/shadow angle, are there *truly* any concepts of shadow and light that wouldn't be covered solely by "lighting"?

Comment: @Makoto shadow is a separate attribute  when working in guis like unity. There's a whole lot of stuff in there and I see it as relevant. either way it's not something to lose sleep over. :)

Comment: But if we see merit in both shadow and light how about making those a synonym of [tag:lightning]? That does require that we cleanup [tag:lightning] as its wiki suggest the tag is used for a Thunderbird tool. The wiki proposals from this answer can then move into the wiki of the ligthning tag

Comment: @rene lightning is a totally different thing. Lighting != lightning

Comment: @YvetteColomb I knew something went wrong there! Blame it on lack of coffee. But I assume you get my point, right?

Comment: @rene yeh, I think that's prob a better idea than putting shadow under light. Lighting is more inclusive

Comment: Shadow and light don'tneed different tags IMO, simply from the expertise angle. I haven't played woth display in a long while, but unless things changed massively, I can't see an expert at "light" not also be an expert at "shadow", no?

Comment: @Patrice added a second answer to cover this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345293/3956566

Comment: Illumination might be a better tag to use for such? If we need a tag at all for this.